# Angular Boilerplate not reading abp

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, aspnetboilerplate

hello hile working on boilerplate project im now learning to consume services from the backend (asp .net) on angular via http requests, so i was trying to add delete method on **mycomponent.ts** but my typescript won't read abp variable
and i cant import the **animations: [appModuleAnimation()]** are they related?
for no reason here is my component code:

```
import { PagedListingComponentBase, PagedRequestDto } from './../../../../../../shared/paged-listing-component-base';
import { FamilleImmobilisationDto } from './../../../dtos/famille-immobilisation';
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FamilleimmobilisationService } from '../../../services/familleimmobilisation.service';

class PagedFamilleImmobilisiationRequestDto extends PagedRequestDto {
  keyword: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-familleimmobilisation',
  templateUrl: './familleimmobilisation.component.html',
  animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
  styleUrls: ['./familleimmobilisation.component.css']
})
export class FamilleimmobilisationComponent extends PagedListingComponentBase<FamilleImmobilisationDto> {
  familleImmobilisations: FamilleImmobilisationDto[] = [];
  keyword = '';
  advancedFiltersVisible = false;

  constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _familleImmobilisationService: FamilleimmobilisationService,
    private _modalService: BsModalService
  )
  {
    super(injector);
  }

  createFamilleImmobilisation(): void {
    this.showCreateOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog();
  }
  editFamilleImmobilisation(familleimob: FamilleImmobilisationDto): void {
    this.showCreateOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog(familleimob.id);
  }

  clearFilters(): void {
    this.keyword = '';
    this.getDataPage(1);
  }

  protected list(
    request: PagedFamilleImmobilisiationRequestDto,
    pageNumber: number,
    finishedCallback: Function
  ): void {
    request.keyword = this.keyword;
    console.log(request.keyword);
    this._familleImmobilisationService
      .getAll()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          finishedCallback();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.familleImmobilisations = data.result;
        console.log(this.familleImmobilisations)
        this.showPaging(data, pageNumber);
      });
  }


  protected delete(familleimob: FamilleImmobilisationDto): void {
     
    abp.message.confirm(
      this.l('familleimobDeleteWarningMessage', familleimob.code),
      undefined,
      (result: boolean) => {
        if (result) {
          this._familleImmobilisationService.delete(familleimob.id).subscribe(() => {
            abp.notify.success(this.l('SuccessfullyDeleted'));
            this.refresh();
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private showCreateOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog(id?: string): void {
    let createOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog: BsModalRef;
    if (!id) {/*
      createOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog = this._modalService.show(
        CreateBanqueDialogComponent,
        {
          class: 'modal-lg',
        }
      );*/
    } else {/*
      createOrEditFamilleImmobilisationDialog = this._modalService.show(
        EditBanqueDialogComponent,
        {
          class: 'modal-lg',
          initialState: {
            id: id,
          },
        }
      );*/
    }

    /*createOrEditBanqueDialog.content.onSave.subscribe(() => {
      this.refresh();
    });*/
  }





}
```

here is some screenshots for more details :
[image: appmoduleanimationimport]

no import suggestion here:
[image: missingappmoduleanimationimport]

not reading abp variable:
[image: canfindnamebp]

Comment: Which version of Angular are you on? Have you run `yarn` or `npm install`?

Comment: See [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#5272](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/5272).

Comment: I'd just delete this question. Screenshots of code are not useful, as visually impaired users and search engine crawlers can't use them (and the alt text "screenshot1", "screenshot2", etc. will not help).

Comment: @HereticMonkey i did'nt know about the importance of the pciture name as u can see im new here, im developing,I edited and fixed the photo name issue , and i found these screenshots are very interesting and more helpful for angular and visual code beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It's Solved actually it was my bad,i forgot to call my modul on the app-routing module so after adding that call,the import of **[appModuleAnimation()]** so it fixed the abp Warning also.:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
{ 
                        path: 'immobilisation', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/immobilisation/immobilisation.module').then(m => m.ImmobilisationModule) 
                    },
```

[image: import showed]